# Android: Splash Screen re-opens app to second page even if app is quit during splash screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

Ok, so i created a very simple splash screen using this tutorial:

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-make-a-basic-splash-screen/

The problem is that if the user hits the home button or the back button to exit the app during the splash screens duration then the app will re-open to the second screen after the splash screen would have been done if the user did no exit.

My code is pretty much that of the tutorial. any help?

Thanks

Comment: wrong in the way taht they get in the way of a seamless user experience and are usually functionally pointless and most of the time simply a timer waiting (and having the user wait also)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified the code to make use of the lifecycle methods better. enjoyed changing it.  :)

```
   public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

        protected int _splashTime = 5000; 

        private Thread splashTread;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);


            final SplashScreen sPlashScreen = this; 

            // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
            splashTread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {                   
                        synchronized(this){
                            wait(_splashTime);
                        }

                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {} 
                    finally {

                        if(!isFinishing()) // This pretty useful boolean val tells if 
 //user has pressed the back button. very useful.
                        {Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Main.class);

                        startActivity(i);
                         finish();
                         }


                        stop();
                    }
                }
            };

            splashTread.start();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {


            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"exec---",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                synchronized(splashTread){
                    splashTread.notifyAll();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPause() {

            super.onPause();

            if(splashTread.getState()==Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING){
                //Thread is still waiting and Activity is paused. Means user has pressed Home. Bail out
                finish();
            }

        }
    }
```

My point of view is that the use of Splash Screen is not frequent but maybe needed. If you are doing heavy work behind the screen( such as games).

Comment: Thank you very much. The splash screen as of now is useless (and i understand why people do not like them) but my reasoning for having this one is 1. the people who i am working with want it 2. i may need that time to load images from a server (lots of images so it may take some time). also, i am new to app dev and thought it would be fun to implement one and know how to

Comment: Welcome.  It may be needed if data is huge. Although in case of images loading, go for  "lazy Loading of images",( there is a very nice example by Romain Guy, Android Shelves or something) so that the user can continue working with your app while images are loading.