# Splash Screen start activity depending on preference?

Tags: android, splash-screen, preference

I'm doing some more renovations to my app and I'm wanting to allow the user to select from two different (although very similar) UI's. I already have both different styles set up but I'm still very new to building applications.

Basically here's what I'm wanting to happen:

- On the first launch show the splash screen I've created with two buttons and instructions on what to do (choose which UI they would like to have) and store their choice somewhere
- On any launch after they have made their decision send them to the UI they have chosen and not show the splash screen
- Have an option (somewhere in the options menu) to allow them to change the UI of the application

The only thing that I'm having trouble with is the java for the splash screen. If someone could help me with that, then I SHOULD be able to work up the rest myself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for the splash screen to be appear only at the first time of running the application by using the shared preferences.
Try this,

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
    private long splashDelay = 1500;
    int counter;
    SharedPreferences app_preferences;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        counter = app_preferences.getInt("counter", 1);
        System.out.println("count is..." + counter);

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
                if (counter == 1) {
                    Intent in = new Intent(Splash.this, Yourclass1.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(Splash.this, Yourclass2.class);
                    startActivity(hackbookIntent);
                }
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("counter", +(counter + 1));
                editor.commit();

            }

        };

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, splashDelay);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a great start! Thanks for that little nugget of code. Now I just have to figure out how to do some of those things on button click instead of on a timer =)

Comment: Here the timer is using only for the splash screen delay, you can set it to a button click, and store any key for the buttonclick and store in sharedpref, and for the next time you can do with that value for which screen to show..

Comment: After working a bit with that code I was able to get exactly what I was wanting. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Check the answer at this link for a sample splashscreen: 
[Android: Splash Screen re-opens app to second page even if app is quit during splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791570/android-splash-screen-re-opens-app-to-second-page-even-if-app-is-quit-during-sp/9792191#9792191)
Instead of using a thread to timeout, wait for the user to click one of the two buttons from your layout and save it in a shared preference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
private Editor prefsEditor;
private static final String APP_SHARED_PREFS = "com.demo.test.Login_preferences";
private static final String APP_CHOICE = "Choice";
private static final String APP_DESIGN = "Design";
private static final String APP_DEVEL = "Develop";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String choice = getValueforKey(APP_CHOICE);
    if(choice.length() == 0){
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button design = (Button) findViewById(R.id.des);
    Button dev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dev);

    design.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            saveKey(APP_CHOICE,APP_DESIGN);
            Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this , Design.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    dev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            saveKey(APP_CHOICE,APP_DEVEL);
            Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this , Develop.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
    }else if(choice.equals(APP_DESIGN)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this , Design.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else if(choice.equals(APP_DEVEL)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this , Develop.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}

public String getValueforKey(String Key)
{
    this.sharedPrefs =getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPrefs.getString(Key, "");
}

public void saveKey(String Key, String value) {
    this.sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     this.prefsEditor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString(Key, value);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}
}
```